# Group XML elements with comma seperated values with XSLT program

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

We are new to xslt programming, can you please help us with xslt program.
We need to group xml elements based on "id" tag and concatenate the other xml tag with comma.

input xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <row>
  <id>123</id>
  <functional_manager__c.users>1234567</functional_manager__c.users>
 </row>
 <row>
  <id>123</id>
  <functional_manager__c.users>1200000</functional_manager__c.users>
 </row>
 <row>
  <id>111</id>
  <functional_manager__c.users>11111111</functional_manager__c.users>
 </row>
 <row>
  <id>111</id>
  <functional_manager__c.users>2222222</functional_manager__c.users>
 </row>
 <row>
  <id>123</id>
  <editor__v.users>1234567</editor__v.users>
  </row>
  <row>
   <id>123</id>
   <editor__v.users>1200000</editor__v.users>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>111</id>
    <learning_partner__c.users>11111111</learning_partner__c.users>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>111</id>
    <learning_partner__c.users>2222222</learning_partner__c.users>
  </row>
  </root>
```

Required Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <row>
  <id>123</id>
  <functional_manager__c.users>1234567,1200000</functional_manager__c.users>
 </row>
 <row>
  <id>111</id>
  <functional_manager__c.users>11111111,2222222</functional_manager__c.users>
 </row>
 <row>
  <id>123</id>
  <editor__v.users>1234567,1200000</editor__v.users>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>111</id>
    <learning_partner__c.users>11111111,2222222</learning_partner__c.users>
  </row>
  </root>
```

code we tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl wd xsd this env"
  xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
   <Sharingsettings>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/root/row" group-by="id">
    <row>
     <ID>
      <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
      </ID>
      <functional_manager__c.users>
       <xsl:value-of select="//current-group()//functional_manager__c.users">

    </xsl:value-of>
     </functional_manager__c.users>
     </row>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
     </Sharingsettings>
     </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

we are trying with XSLT program but it is not giving required output properly.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Look at the `group-adjacent` examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 3 you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-adjacent="id">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="row/*[not(self::id)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/*[node-name() = node-name(current())]" separator=","/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried above code and it is giving giving the error like " 
net.sf.saxon.trans.UncheckedXPathException: There is no current group"

Comment: Which version and edition of Saxon exactly do you use, did you run the exact code sample I posted or some adaption with changes? Also, do you use normal processing or did you perhaps try to use streaming (where indeed `current-group()` wouldn't work the way I have used it above)?

Comment: The sample is online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jy6KM7c and there works flawlessly (with Saxon 10.6 as the XSLT processor).

Comment: Another explanation might the use of namespaces in the input sample, you would need to edit your question to show us representative samples to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Martin, our tool uses xslt 3.0 with SAXON EE 9.9.1.6. where we are getting "net.sf.saxon.trans.UncheckedXPathException: There is no current group" error in our tool.

Comment: Do you get that error with Saxon EE 9.9.1.6 for exactly that input sample from your question and exactly my XSLT sample from the answer? Or are there any differences between the code samples? I can't explain the error message for the code you have posted together with the XSLT I have posted, unless streaming is perhaps used. But I would expect the code to fail the streamability analysis anyway with a `group-by` selecting a child node.

Comment: I've tried Martin's code with several Saxon versions including Saxon EE 9.9.1.6 and I can't reproduce the error. I'd like to know what's going on here, because although there are cases where "There is no current group" is a legitimate error, it should never be exposed as an `UncheckedXPathException`.

Comment: @MichaelKay, the use of `xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"` suggests Saxon is used in the context of that Workday tool, I think they might by default try to run with streaming, because they tend to have large datasets. But that is just a guess and I don't know how they could set up streaming but not run into the rejection of the posted code by the streamability analysis.

Comment: hi martin, Thanks for your reply. Code is working now in my version but issue is it is not giving output properly for large input please check below link  https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jy6KM7c/5

Comment: @vijay, consider to tell us exactly which result you want and which part in the linked example is wrong or missing. As far as I can see, in your input sample the `row` elements forming an adjacent group had the same child element so the proposed solution is based on that structure and should work, even for larger sets of rows. However, in your linked sample the input `row`s seem to have the same `id` child so the grouping should continue to work, but then sometimes have two or more different child elements. I think better ask a new question with clear samples of input and wanted output.

Comment: @vijay, I have tried to guess what you might want in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jy6KM7c/6, if that does not give the wanted result then please ask a new question where you detail a small but representative sample of the input and the wanted output plus a verbal description as to which elements are to be merged and which ones not.

Comment: hi Martin, thanks you, This is exactly what i want (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jy6KM7c/6 ) but issue is  "id"  447 role  "approver__v.users" giving output in different group.

Comment: @vijay, it is not clear what you want. Take the time to ask a new question with short but representative samples of XML input and matching output, together with a verbal description of the rules which elements to group and merge and which ones not. Note that in your sample of this question there are for instance various `row` elements with the same `id` `111` which do, according to your wanted output, not form a single group but two, as I understood and implemented, you only want to group adjacent `row`s with the same `id`.

Comment: Thanks martin. I will open another question with clear description. Thank you so much for your support and help. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I don't think it's streaming-related. Use of current-group() in a streaming context would give a different (static) error. I think this error can only be because the `match="row/*[...]"` template fires when there is no `for-each-group` currently executing.